# Looking for a tuple-like data storage solution

Tags: c#, .net

I am using C# to design a program to save a lot of data with similar structure but not the same on the disk.

These structures are composed of several fixed types of fields, which are a bit like tuples.

For example, "Tom met Jack in the morning" and "It rained on the farm in the afternoon".

For the former, I need to store 4 fields

```
{
DateTime time=morning;
Person P1=Tom;
Person P2=Jack;
EventTag tag="meet";
}
```

For the latter, I hope to avoid storing empty Person fields (for saving storage space). So just store

```
{
Datetime time=afternoon;
Location location=farm;
EventTag tag="rain";
}
```

OK. The fields used are fixed, there are dozens of them such as Datetime, Person, Item,Location,etc.,but I may only save 3-6 kinds each time.I tried to use tuple to save them, and it can be realized, but I encountered trouble when reading the fields-tuple only has item1,item2... and the type of the field is not clear.

So now I've turned to two attempts: one is to create a huge class that contains all the dozens of fields that may appear, write the fields I need and leave the rest blank. But after serialization, writing a large number of empty fields will make the stored data larger.

Another attempt is theoretically possible. It can take into account performance and storage space, but the upfront investment is a bit large-I combine the fields needed each time into a new class, and they look like this:

```
interfaceIfields{GetTime();GetLocation();GetPerson();Getxxxx...and so on}

class Time1_Person2: Ifields
{
DateTime time=morning;
Person P1=Tom;
Person P2=Jack;

public Datetime GetTime()=>time;
public Location GetLocation() => null;
public List<Person> GetPerson()=> new List<Person>{P1,P2};
//....and so on.
}
```

Then use the same 'Ifields' interface to read all the different combinations of class fields. This method can be done in theory, but it is too tiring when there are many combinations of fields.

Is there a better solution?

It is desirable to minimize storage space while maintaining performance when accessing fields.

Comment: Serialization to what though?

Comment: You can take a look at Winform's [PropertyStore](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/blob/main/src/System.Windows.Forms/src/System/Windows/Forms/PropertyStore.cs) class.

Comment: Serialize to binary (I'm looking for serialization libraries like protobuf, messagepack and compare their storage sizes).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using System.Text.Json you could use [JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/ignore-properties?pivots=dotnet-7-0#ignore-all-null-value-properties) to skip writing any null fields:

```
JsonSerializerOptions options = new()
{
    DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull
};

string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize<MyClass>(myObject, options);
```

Newtonsoft json have [NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/NullValueHandlingIgnore.htm) to do the same thing.

If you are using a modern size focused binary serialization protocol, like protobuf, I would suspect that optional values are just omitted completely by default.